# Parse and filter XML

Tags: php, xml, parsing, filter

I would like to parse an XML with *Simple DOM Parser*. My code returns all the desired content of the `"uri"` tag properly.

Example:

```
"http://www.domain.com/Start/A/93243"
"http://www.domain.com/Start/B/239483"
"http://www.domain.com/Start/C/93433"
"http://www.domain.com/Start/B/34299"
"http://www.domain.com/Start/A/234343"
```

Now I need to filter the returned values. My script should only return the `"uri"` content starting with a specific text e.g. `"http://www.domain.com/Start/A/"`. So my result should be:

```
"http://www.domain.com/Start/A/93243"
"http://www.domain.com/Start/A/234343"
```

That´s my starting code:

```
<?php 
require_once ('simple_html_dom.php');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load( 'xml-url' );

$uri = $dom->getElementsByTagName('uri');

foreach ($uri as $uri) {
    echo $uri->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You include a library, but you're using the DOMDocument. So you do not need the library. The DOMDocument is part of PHP ext/dom. Here is another class that allows you to use Xpath to nodes from a DOM document.

Select all `href` attribute nodes of all `a` element nodes:

`//a/@href`

Filter them by string prefix:

`//a/@href[starts-with(., "http://www.domain.com/Start/A/")]`

DOMXpath::evaluate() is the method you need to use to fetch nodes:

```
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate(
  '//a/@href[starts-with(., "http://www.domain.com/Start/A/")]'
);
```

Complete example: https://eval.in/142509

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<body>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/Start/A/93243">1</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/Start/B/239483">1</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/Start/C/93433">1</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/Start/B/34299">1</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/Start/A/234343">1</a>
</body>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate(
  '//a/@href[starts-with(., "http://www.domain.com/Start/A/")]'
);

foreach ($hrefs as $hrefAttribute) {
  var_dump($hrefAttribute->value);
}
```

Output:

```
string(35) "http://www.domain.com/Start/A/93243"
string(36) "http://www.domain.com/Start/A/234343"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/strpos) which returns the index of the search string, so you can check if it is `0`, which means it starts with the search string.

```
foreach ($uri as $uri) {
    if(strpos($uri->nodeValue, 'http://www.domain.com/Start/A/') === 0){
        echo $uri->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```